# How to setup Vi Editing Mode for zsh

Tags: zsh, vi

I want to set vi in editing mode in zsh (I am using oh-my-zsh) at start automatically when I open my shell, so at the beginning of my `.zshrc` I have tried the following code:

`set -o vi`

or

`bindkey -v`

but when pressing enter in the shell I cannot enter the vi mode.

If I tried one of the two commands in the shell, it works.

Basically I want zsh to start in vi edit mode.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you mark the answer which seems the best for you?

Answer (score 71):

`bindkey -v` is enough to enable vi mode in ZSH. If you are worried the setting will be overwritten by another plugin, put the setting at the bottom of your `~/.zshrc`.

After vi mode is enabled, you enter the "insert" mode by default. To enter "normal" mode, use <kbd>Esc</kbd>. And <kbd>i</kbd> or <kbd>a</kbd> to switch back to "insert" mode.

BTW, [softmoth/zsh-vim-mode](https://github.com/softmoth/zsh-vim-mode) is the most powerful vim mode plugin I've ever used in ZSH.

Using `bindkey -v` may take over functionality such as history search with <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. To restore that particular behavior, add the following lines after `bindkey -v`:

```
bindkey ^R history-incremental-search-backward 
bindkey ^S history-incremental-search-forward
```

Other bindings can be found in the ZSH manual [Standard Widgets](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Standard-Widgets) section.

Comment: This seems to have the adverse action of unbinding `ctrl + R`

Comment: @progfan Indeed it does. I this helped me: https://vimawesome.com/plugin/zsh-history-substring-search

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but if you hit esc to go into command mode, you can then do searches like you would in vi.

Answer (score 37):

If you are using https://ohmyz.sh/ you can add `vi-mode` to the list of plugins in ~/.zshrc:

```
plugins=(git vi-mode)
```

Comment: and to get the cursor mode indicator add `INSERT_MODE_INDICATOR="%F{yellow}+%f"
` and to map `jj` to `esc` add `bindkey -M viins 'jj' vi-cmd-mode`

Comment: I've done this, it doesn't error or anything, but it doesn't seem to do anything. Do I have to do something else to use/activate it?

Comment: @stevec maybe open a new shell or terminal?

Comment: @stevec either open a new shell or terminal, or run

`source <path_to_.zshrc>`. The default location is ~/.zshrc

Comment: Useful to know: press `vv` in normal mode (and not `v` like in bash vi-mode) to edit the command-line in vim editor.

Answer (score 12):

If you don't mind using a plugin for vi mode in zsh, here is a better choice for you, which I wrote, to quickly reach it.

> [zsh-vi-mode](https://github.com/jeffreytse/zsh-vi-mode): A better and friendly vi(vim) mode plugin for ZSH.

After adding this plugin, then you can input with vi-mode like this:

[image: demo]

Comment: I've stopped using this plugin temporarily. The documentation is just a bit sparse, like..how does / work for history search? It breaks the filtered history I'm now used to, I definitely need history search e.g '/' at least.

Comment: Another drawback of the above plugin is that it takes over by default all existing bindings and keymaps: this should never be the default behaviour.

Comment: For the documentation part, you can look for clues from source code, or create an issue. And if you don't take over some default keybindings, you would find that some issues are hard to settle down, it's some kind of trade off.

Comment: The fact that you're the developer of this project needs to be explicitly stated for this answer to not be spam